# Pourquoi dit-on réunion et pas union (des ensembles) ?

Tags: mathématiques

> Dans ce contexte, ces deux mots sont synonymes (cf. entrées union
> [archive] et réunion [archive] sur le portail lexical du CNRTL). Ils
> sont utilisés indifféremment, parfois dans un même ouvrage, comme S.
> Balac et L. Chupin, Analyse et algèbre : cours de mathématiques de
> deuxième année avec exercices corrigés et illustrations avec Maple,
> Lausanne, PPUR, 2008, 1035 p. (ISBN 978-2-88074-782-4, lire en ligne
> [archive]).

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(math%C3%A9matiques)#cite_note-1

Pourquoi les deux mots sont-ils acceptés et considérés équivalents dans ce contexte ? Pourquoi pas tout simplement union ?

Comment: Sans doute parce qu'une réunion peut être passagère, plus courte que l'union. La réunion des deux familles a été faite pour assister à l'union de deux de leurs enfants. La réunion est circonstancielle, l'union scelle un nouvel état.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le terme reconnu traditionnellement est « réunion ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9union)) − MATH. Réunion (de deux ensembles). Ensemble constitué par la totalité de leurs éléments. La réunion de A et de B se note A ∪ B et se lit « A union B » ou « A réunion B » (Bouvier-GeorgeMath.1979).

Bourbaki, par exemple, n'utilise que « réunion » pour sa théorie des ensembles.

Traditionnellement aussi , on utilise « union » pour le connecteur logique de disjonction (ou).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/union)) ♦ LOG., MATH., INFORMAT. ,,Opération logique destinée à rechercher la présence d'un élément A ou d'un élément B ou, éventuellement, des deux simultanément. Elle est représentée par l'opérateur logique OU inclusif . Synon. addition, disjonction, réunion, somme logique (v. somme1A). La « petite » théorie des ensembles, qui se contente des notations d'appartenance, d'inclusion, d'union et d'intersection (...), doit être abordée de façon très pragmatique, appuyée sur des exemples concrets et sur des diagrammes d'Euler-Venn (Warusfel, Math. mod., 1969, p. 64).

On compare les définitions de « réunion » et d'« union » reproduites ci-dessous (TLFi).

> ([Réunion](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9union)) A. −  Action de mettre côte à côte, de faire se toucher, de mettre ensemble; résultat de cette action. Synon. assemblage, juxtaposition, liaison, rapprochement, union.

> ([Union](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/union)) b) Rapprochement de deux ou plusieurs choses, d'éléments tendant à former un tout harmonieux. Synon. adhérence, alliance, association, cohérence, cohésion, combinaison, connexion, contexture, correspondance, liaison, mariage (au fig.).

Bien que dans les synonymes de « réunion » on trouve le terme « union », on s'aperçoit que les connotations des synonymes (assemblage, juxtaposition), sauf en ce qui concerne « liaison » et « rapprochement », sont libres de concepts d'un ordre supérieur : il s'agit d'une simple  idée de considération d'un nouveau tout qui  n'est ni le premier ni le second, mais le tout  correspondant à « l'apport » des deux touts initiaux. Cette idée se perd un peu dans le terme « liaison » parce qu'il insinue l'idée de relation, qui, en dehors d'un concept mathématique pur est absente de « assemblage » et « juxtaposition ».
Si on examine la définition de « union », on voit tout d'abord qu'il s'agit d'un rapprochement, ce qui implique un lien, qui n'existe pas dans la notion d'ensemble en dehors de celui de figurer sous une même propriété (et il est très simple : A U B c'est ce qui est dans A et  ce qui est dans B) ; ensuite, il est question d'un *tout harmonieux* et cela est une notion qui relève de l'esthétique et possiblement d'autres considérations comme celle du côté utilitaire de la chose, lesquelles sont absolument absentes du concept de la réunion d'ensembles. De plus, les synonymes de ce second terme (adhérence, alliance, association, cohérence, cohésion, combinaison, connexion, contexture, correspondance, liaison, mariage) ne parlent que de liens plus ou moins sophistiqués dont certains sont typiques seulement des relations humaines. Tout cela est beaucoup trop pour le concept de réunion d'ensemble, lequel se veut une « opération » la plus simple possible.
À mon avis, les déductions ci-dessus révèlent le bien-fondé du choix de « réunion » comme nom de l'opération, bien que, il faut le reconnaitre, si « réunion » n'avait pas existé on se serait bien accommodé du terme « union ».

Pour mieux mettre ce raisonnement en perspective, je rappellerai que dans la situation qui consiste à faire de deux troupeaux qui paissent chacun dans une prairie un seul troupeau comprenant les animaux des deux dans une seule prairie, il est seulement idiomatique  de parler de la *réunion* des deux troupeaux et que dans le cas d'une association d'états qui conjointement forment un autre état, il est seulement idiomatique de parler de l'*union* de ces états.

Pourquoi est-ce que « union » a commencé à déplacer « réunion » ? Ce n'est pas parfaitement clair à mes yeux, mais il y a deux sources à ne pas négliger dans cette évolution : d'abord l'influence grandissante, depuis plusieurs décennies, de la littérature mathématique anglo-saxonne, dans laquelle le terme correspondant est « union », et ensuite  la proximité graphique et sémantique des termes « réunion » et « union »  combinée avec la pratique de lire « A union B » pour  « A U B ».

Comment: Interesting analysis. As a(n) (applied) (now retired) mathematician, I have never used "réunion", only "union". Is it because, intuitively the added syllable "re" adds nothing to the concept ? Or, as you underline it, because of the dominant English scientific litterature ?

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker I tend to think that the reason,  as time goes by, is more and more the exposure (whatever the source) and that mathematicians are few to wonder about the meaning of words; that is not their domain, they don't have much time either, and then how could  they doubt the books and the teachers, which is what  inculcate the terms? I, personally didn't begin to appreciate consciously the real difference between the two words before I actually grappled with the dictionary definitions and applied them to some examples, which was not early in life.

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker Why do you think that some French mathematician once decided to replace the name "différence symétrique" by the name "discrépance"? I believe that  the reason is that the meaning they read into "différence symétrique" wasn't satisfying.

Comment: In mathematics, creation of concepts is one thing, creation of specific words for naming them is another. The process is comparable to creation of concepts and associated words in philosophy. Here, I think of course more to German language than to English language : for example when Heidegger "forged" his "da-sein", he promoted a certain concept with a well-chosen word, with the proper essence of German language words construction, but requiring in other langages, either to use the German word without translation or use periphrases in order to convey the associated concept.

Comment: Il manque le typage des groupes pour codifier mon commentaire : Groupe-Famille A (***R**éunion Bourbakienne*) Groupe-Famille B → Groupe Couple N[ouveau] avec 1 seul élément de A et 1 seul élément de B, **u**ni[on] dans l'état de couple qui peut récursivement construire une nouvelle famille à condition de reconnaître au moins un enfant, pour une famille basée sur la procréation.

Comment: @Personne Je ne suis pas familier avec ces concepts ; il me semble que vous parlez de produit cartésien et des couples qui composent ces ensembles particuliers, mais tout cela n'a rien à voir avec la réunion, en ce qui concerne le concept basique, et ici c'est tout ce qui nous concerne, le concept basique.

Comment: Ce sont des éléments de la grammaire Booléenne appliqué ici à une réalité sociologique où un groupe est forcément *un groupe de [suivi d'une référence]* en gardant le concept basique vous oblitérer les différences d'état et de comportement de groupes distincts, ce qui rend ensuite la compréhension de l'équation par un tiers beaucoup plus difficile. Dans mes souvenirs lycéens, je n'ai pas souvenir qu'il y ait un signe, un accent ou symbole particulier pour marquer ce changement d'état dans une association d'éléments de la même famille de groupes.

Comment: @Personne Vous parlez de quelque chose que je ne connais pas du tout, mais il n'y a aucun doute que cela n'a strictement rien à voir avec le sujet de la question, qui est pourquoi tel nom plutôt qu'un autre pour le concept mathématique de réunion ensembliste.

Comment: Il serait intéressant de connaître les exemples du livre cité pour savoir si les mots différents utilisés "pour le concept mathématique de réunion ensembliste" sont dans le même contexte, ou si cela était dû tout simplement au fait qu'il y ait deux auteurs.

Comment: @Personne Ce n'est pas le problème ; au fil du temps les mathématiciens en France, qui utilisaient un terme (dans tous les manuels et papiers), c'est à dire le terme « réunion », se sont mis à utiliser pour ce même concept le terme « union » ; on a donc de nos jours dans certains manuels un terme, dans d'autres le second, mais ils nomment la même chose. User Dimitris était  curieux de savoir pourquoi il y a de nos jours deux termes dans l'usage.

Comment: Généralement, il est peut-être utile de rappeler que [_réunion_](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/r%C3%A9union) dérive du verbe _réunir_ sur le modèle d'_union_ alors il est difficile de l'évacuer complètement.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Oui, il ne s'agit que d'une forte propension pour une catégorie de sens ; il est manifeste que les deux catégories empiètent l'une sur l'autre.